# How to use 'vi' navigation commands within a shell script

Tags: shell, vim, vi

I’m trying to use `ex file <<EOF` *vi* commands to go to end of a file, go up 100 lines, and delete from that position to end of file.

How can I use the `G` command to go to end of file within a shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash
ex data1 <<EOF
G
100G
dG
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual method is to use Ex commands via `:help -c`:

```
$ ex data1 -c '$-99,$d|wq'
```

The argument is read like this:

```
<range><command>|<command>
```

where:

- `$-99,$` is a `:help range` that starts 99 lines above the last line and ends on the last line,
- `:help :d` cuts the given range,
- `:help :|` separates that first command from the next,
- `:help :wq` writes the file and quits.

Alternatively, you should be able to use several `-c` arguments:

```
$ ex data1 -c '$-99,$d' -c 'wq'
```

Comment: THANK YOU ROMAINI and stack overflow community.